# Mysql / Big Query to Find when a customer loses access for the first time (Gap / Island)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, google-bigquery

I'm hoping the query will work both in Mysql and BigQuery

For each customer I need to find the first date they had a subscription and the first date that they stopped having any subscriptions (e.g. a break in subscription).  A customer can have multiple overlapping subscriptions.  Once a customer stops having access then future subscriptions are not considered.

This is a sample table with a few rows.  The actual table will have millions of rows and thousands of customers.

using this sample data:

```
select * from test_sub order by customer_id, effect_date, expire_date;
```

| subscription_id | customer_id | effect_date | expire_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-04-25 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 |

The answer should be:

| customer_id | min(effect_date) | max(expire_date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-04-25 00:00:00 |

Comment: Just wanted to ask if the max(expire_date) data for customer_id "2" which is 2022-04-25 00:00:00 is correct? if we are getting max expire date 2022-10-01 00:00:00 feels more correct since this is greater?

Comment: It is 2022-04-25 because it's not about the max expire date.  It's about when this customer lost access for the first time.  So he had continuous access up until 2022-04-25.